# Checking SSL works before migrating a site

Tags: wordpress, ssl, hosting

I have a website on server 1 that has an SSL certificate, I need to move a new developed site to server 2 which has a new SSL certificate.  The SSL has been installed on server 2, is there anyway to check if the site and the ssl certificate works before changing the nameservers from server 1 to server 2.

I have tried editing the hosts file on my computer with the IP address of server 2 and the site loads, but as it only shows the IP address in the url bar so there doesn't seem to be a way to tell if the SSL is working, if i add https:// to the domain IP it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the hostfile to the second server with the correct domainname it should listen as if it were used from a nameserver from the outside world.

For example, if you want to test server 2 with IP 194.194.194.194 with the domainname www.example.com you should add this line to your hostfile:

*194.194.194.194 www.example.com*

After you add this it is possible to go to https://www.example.com which should serve you the certificate if everything is configured right.

Cheers!

Comment: Ok im seeing the files as they are on the server, so im guessing this means that it has worked?

Comment: If you see the correct certificate loaded it is indeed working correct :)